# Delay RACObserve subcribeNext call to one per second

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm observing a class' attribute that changes every .2 second. I would like to delay the observing to each second.

I tried:

```
RACObserve(object, keyPath: "attribute").delay(1).subscribeNext { 
    // DO STUFF
}
```

But the `subscribeNext` is still called every .2 second.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this:

```
RACObserve(object, keyPath: "attribute").combineLatestWith(RACSignal.interval(1, onScheduler: RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler()))
  .subscribeNext { 
  // DO STUFF
}
```

You can add a `map` to get only the `attribute` value instead of a `RACTuple`